# What is our understanding of what our (i.e. observable) universe has expanded into?

Tags: space-expansion, big-bang, observable-universe

In his latest Fermilab video, Dr. Don Lincoln [explained](https://youtu.be/bZdvSJyHvUU?t=251):

> (...) even though we shrunk the visible universe down to tiny size, the number line is still infinite. That means that, even when the universe began, it might have already started out to be infinite in size. So that's kind of a mind-blower.

Consider my mind blown.

I always thought that even if *beyond the observable*[a] is at least 500x bigger (according to the same video), shrinking the universe as a whole would equally shrink the farthest regions to the same point[b] (the farthest out, the bigger the shrink for a given duration).

I *presume* it's because there's no supporting data (is that correct?), even if it is a logical deduction. But suppose the universe indeed was already infinite before/at/after the Big Bang, then what is our current understanding of what the observable universe had expanded into – space expanding into space?[c]

---

[a] Is there a better name for it? I couldn't find one.
[b] I understand it's not a center, but anywhere can be that point.
[c] If the beyond the observable didn't share that point, and it isn't known for sure, then equally it isn't known for sure there was nothing, what implications does that have or what is known about that?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/123208

Comment: BTW, when cosmologists say that the whole universe might be finite, they are *not* claiming that there's a finite blob of galaxies sitting inside an infinite void. If the universe is finite, then the total volume is finite (but expanding) and full of galaxies.

Comment: @PM2Ring: This is how I understand it too (until I saw that video). I'll peruse the linked post, and see if it solves my question, thanks for the link.

Comment: @PM2Ring: It's very clear now, thanks, though I don't have the rep to VTC my own question.